# Database connection with multithread in java

Tags: java

How to handle database connection with multithreaded application. I have developed one application that created more thread. But when i run application it run correctly but after some time application is going to hang....?? what i have to do ..? How to handle Database connection with multithreaded application .?

Comment: what do you mean by "it hangs"? Where does it hang? Do you have a stack trace / heap dump when it hangs?

Comment: my mean to say my application do nothing...? there is no exception or any memory leakage..... I thing i am suffer this for database connection

Comment: What Database do you use? I know about some Memory-Leak Problems within the mySQL JDBC Driver. If your application start to slow down, it could be the memory-consumption.

Comment: yes i am using mysql JDBC driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably would like to use a connection pool. My recommendation is [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/).

Answer (score 0):

Database connections and threading need not be completely related.

Where are you fetching your DB connections from? Is it a central data source? Or a custom wrapper over JDBC connection? Or are you fetching it from a DB connection pool? Or are you creating a new connection in each thread?

Comment: thank you .. madhur Actually i am using JDBC connection . and Create single connection for all threads. can i use like this public static synchronize Connection getConnection() instead of public static Connection getConnection()...........?

Comment: No - that won't work, it still allows two threads to access the Connection at the same time. You will have to write a wrapper class around your Connection that performs DB access and synchronize the whole class on the Connection.

Answer (score 0):

Connection in the singular? If you only have one connection then you will have to synchronize your threads access to the connection. Better to use a Database connection pool though; almost all database vendors provide a connection pool implementation.